# How can I combine Wordpress default Tags and bbPress tags into one archive page?

Tags: tags, archives, buddypress, custom-post-type-archives, bbpress

I'm trying to figure out how to combine two taxonomies?

I've got three things going on:

1. Tags from Buddyboss's Forums (Buddypress/bbpress)
2. Tags from The Events Calendar Pro
3. Tags from Wordpress's WP_TAGS

The events calendar uses the standard WP_TAGS that Wordpress blog posts also use, but the forums have their own tag type.

I'd like to combine the tags so that clicking the same word takes you to one page, with forum discussions, blog posts, and events related to that tag.

Is this possible?

Comment: It is possible, you could run a query for both then merge the returned IDs into a single array and loop through that array.  As an example.  There could be better and more efficient methods though.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.